# internet-explorer BHO PDF

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, plugins, acrobat

I developed an IE8 toolbar in C#. The toolbar has a button which when clicked adds some user defined content to the page. I am using a BHO to add the required HTML, CSS & JS to the page. Everything is fine when normal HTML pages are loaded. But, my button isn't working when the loaded page is a pdf document. I found out that the adobe plugin itself is a BHO and IE hands over the document to the plugin. My question is, Is there any way by which I can add content to a pdf page through my BHO?

Thanks, 
simil

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can write plug-ins for Acrobat.  The Adobe docs are [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/API_References/PRCReference/3D_API_Reference/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

When your toolbar makes modifications to the web page, the modifications are in memory and the browser supports web page modifications in memory. When a browse displays a PDF document via a plugin, it is the PDF plugin (not the browser) that needs to in-memory modifications of the displayed document. And, PDF plugins do not provide such support. Theoretically, it is possible for you to make modifications to the PDF document in memory and get it reloaded in the PDF plugin but that requires a PDF processing library or logic in your toolbar.